# Binomial logistic regression in SPSS using survey weights

Tags: logistic, spss, categorical-data, survey

I am running a logistic regression in SPSS with a sample that uses survey weights. The sample size is 1000 and the weights are along the lines of .86 or 1.23 depending on the case. I am using the weights option in the `Data` command to weight my sample before I run my logistic regression but then I get the unweighted frequencies in the `Categorical Variables Coding` part of the output.

At the beginning my output gives me a `Case Processing Summary`, which says `Unweighted cases` with a superscript "a" which then says "If weight is in effect see classification table for the total number of cases."  My classification tables all are properly saying 1000 cases which is right.  I have 7 predictor variables (all categorical) and one outcome variable (dichotomous).  My output seems to make sense, but I am troubled that the frequencies are all the unweighted frequencies.  Are my results still legitimate?  I am afraid that I may not understand the weighting quite properly.

Comment: This appears centred on what SPSS does exactly. If the question is at heart statistical, please rephrase it to make that clear.

Comment: How are you using the weights? You should be using complex samples, not weight cases.

Comment: I think this question could be sufficiently statistical to be on-topic (cf, [interpretation-of-rs-lm-output](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/)). @KristenLindSeal, perhaps you could paste some images of your output & ask for help interpreting it in line w/ your questions.

Comment: Actually this method does not properly handle survey weighting estimation -- it simply treats a weight of e.g. 100 as though it were 100 cases, but doesn't correctly estimate variances (and hence standard errors). See my answer to another question on using SPSS for weighted data [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65492/16974) for more detail.

Comment: The CSLOGISTIC procedure handles survey weights.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality, @JKP. Would you mind expanding this a little?

Comment: Thanks for the help - I have not been able to get back to the lab to work on this more since I posted the question.  I think I was using the wrong technique for weighting and am now trying to figure out the complex samples piece.  Sorry that I also can't figure out if it is okay to comment on my own original question...I appreciate this forum, though, you have been quite helpful.